# SDL geolocation services

Tags: localization

Is there a way we can communicate with Tridion to see where a visitor is connecting from?

The idea is a user visits a page, then determines their location and based on their location then perform the appropriate action.

Comment: Morning Michael. There is no GEO Location service built-in with Tridion, but you can integrate with an external, 3rd party service within the web application code. The following question by Alvin (and the answers) may help you: https://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/3251/71

Comment: That sounds like an Answer.

Comment: Go on then. You've twisted my arm! ;)

Comment: Out-of-curiosity, is this for a privacy requirement, perhaps? Or is it more for a personalization scenario?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no GEO Location service built-in with Tridion, but you can integrate with an external, 3rd party service within the web application code.

The following question by Alvin (and the answers) may help you: [Geolocation options for content delivery](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/3251/71). Pankaj gives a couple of examples of 3rd party GEO Location services that you could use in his answer.

Comment: Also read @JanH's answer in that post. I'd recommend the Ambient Data Framework with a 3rd-party GEO-IP lookup if you want to integrate a few pieces of explicit and implicit user data with other Tridion features. Otherwise application-specific code might be a simpler approach.